# Distance Between Line and Circle

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Consider the circle $C$ given by the equation 
$$(x+5)^2 + (y−10)^2 = 15$$
and the line $L$ given by the equation 
$$y = \frac{1}{2}x−3.$$

1. Find the distance between $C$ and $L$.
2. Find the equation of the line perpendicular to $L$ that goes through the center of the circle $C$.

Comment: I just dont even know where to start or what to do at all

Comment: Hint: Do part 2 before doing part 1, but first, draw a diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrically, the shortest distance from a circle to a straight line is the from the center of the circle perpendicular to the line.  Here, the center of the circle is $(-5, 10)$ and a line through that point, perpendicular to the line $y- 10= -2(x+ 5)$ or $y= -2x$.

Replacing $y$ by that in the equation of the circle, $$(x+5)^2+ (-2x- 10)^2= x^2+ 10x+ 25+ 4x^2+ 40x+ 100= 15$$ or, $$\implies 5x^2+ 50x+ 110= 0$$

This quadratic equation has two solutions.  One is the point on the circle closest to the line, the other is the point on the circle farthest from the line.

Answer (score 2):

1. $\mathcal{C}$ has for equation $(x+5)^2+(y−10)^2=15$ meaning $\mathcal{C}$ has a $\sqrt{15}$ radius and a centre point that we will name $A$ with the following coordinates $A(-5;10)$.

> • PROOF 1
>
> Consider $\left(O,\vec{i},\vec{j}\right)$
>   an orthonormal axis.
>   One equation of the circle $\mathcal{C}$ of centre $A(x_A; y_A)$ and radius $R$ is
>   $(x − x_A)^2 +(y − y_A)^2 = R^2$.

The shortest distance between $A$ and $L$ is the distance between A and its orthonormal projection $A'$. The normal vector of $L$ (denoted $\vec{n}$) and $\vec{A'A}$ are codirectional meaning that the scalar product between these two vectors is the product of their magnitude where $\vec{n}(a;b)$ because $(L) : ax+by+c=0$ : $$\left|\vec{A'A}\cdot\vec{n}\right|=||\vec{A'A}||\times||\vec{n}||$$

> • THEOREM 1
>
> Consider the slope $(d) : ax+by+c$.
>   The normal vector is characterized by $\vec{u}(a;b)$.
>
> • PROOF 2
>
> The scalar product between two vectors is : $$\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}=||\vec{v}||\times||\vec{w}||\times cos\left(\vec{v},\vec{w}\right)$$
>   When two vectors are codirectional, the angle of rotation between these two vectors is $0rad$, where $cos(0)=1$. Therefore :
>
> $$\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}=||\vec{v}||\times||\vec{w}||\times cos\left(\vec{v},\vec{w}\right)=||\vec{v}||\times||\vec{w}||\times1=||\vec{v}||\times||\vec{w}||$$

Knowing the length of a vector is determined by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, thus we have, for $\vec{n}$ : $||\vec{n}||=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. So we have $\left|\vec{A'A}\cdot\vec{n}\right|=||\vec{A'A}||\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. We're looking for the distance $A'A$ :

$$||\vec{A'A}||=\frac{\left|\vec{A'A}\cdot\vec{n}\right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

The scalar product $\left|\vec{A'A}\cdot\vec{n}\right|$ can also be calculated thanks to the coordinates of these two vectors.

> • THEOREM 2
>
> The scalar product is also the sum of the products of the $x$ and the $y$ coordinates. If $\vec{u}(x_u;y_u)$ and $\vec{v}(x_v;y_v)$, therefore : $$\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=x_ux_v+y_uy_v$$

Consider $\vec{A'A}(x_A-x_{A'};y_A-y_{A'})\leadsto\vec{A'A}(-5-x_{A'};10-y_{A'})$ and $\vec{n}(a;b)$, we then have :

$$ \left|\vec{A'A}\cdot\vec{n}\right|=\left|a(-5-x_{A'})+b(10-y_{A'})\right|$$
$$ \left|\vec{A'A}\cdot\vec{n}\right|=\left|-5a-ax_{A'}+10b-by_{A'}\right|$$

The point $A'$, being the orthogonal projection of $A$ on $L$, belongs to $L$, then it respects the equation of a slope, then $ax_{A'}-by_{A'}=c$. So :
$$ \left|\vec{A'A}\cdot\vec{n}\right|=\left|-5a+10b+c \right|$$

Finally we then have : $$||\vec{A'A}||=\frac{\left|-5a+10b+c \right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Knowing that $(L) : y=\dfrac{1}{2}x-3\Leftrightarrow x-2y-6=0$ with $a=1$, $b=-2$, $c=-6$, replacing we have :

$$||\vec{A'A}||=\frac{\left|-5\times1+10\times(-2)-6 \right|}{\sqrt{\left(1\right)^2+(-2)^2}}$$
$$||\vec{A'A}||=\frac{31}{\sqrt{5}}=\dfrac{31\sqrt{5}}{5}$$
$$A'A\approx13.86$$

The closest point of the circle is then at $A'A-R=\dfrac{31\sqrt{5}}{5}-\sqrt{15}=\dfrac{-\sqrt{5}\left(5\sqrt{3}-31\right)}{5}\approx10.0$

2. A line has an equation of the form $y=ax+c$. We consider $(A'A) : y'=a'x+c'$ and $(L) : y=\dfrac{1}{2}x-3$. Two lines are perpendicular if and only if $aa'=-1$.

$$\frac{1}{2}a'=-1$$
$$a'=-2$$

We then have $(A'A) : y=-2x+c'$. Knowing that $A(-5;10)$, then $10=-2\times(-5)+c'$ meaning that $c'=0$, so :

$$(A'A) : y=-2x$$ is the perpendicular line of (L) going threw the center of $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you can use the general formula for the distance between a point and a straight line

$$d=\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},$$

considering the point $(x_0,y_0)$ and the line with equation in the form $ax+by+c=0$. Take the point to be the center of the circle.

For the second part, two lines with equations $y=a_1x+b_1$ and $y=a_2x+b_2$ are perpendicular if $a_1 a_2=-1$, so you can find the slope. Since you also know a point in the line (the center of the circle), you're done.